Headphones Plantronics Poly BT700 mic issues in ubuntu 22.04.4
I have  a Plantronics Poly BT700 headphones. It worked on old ubuntu linux versions like ubuntu 20.04 but with 22.04 it fails.

The main issue is with the microphone, it works but it has milliseconds cut off, so what I talked is not clear. The headphone audio is ok, the problem is only with the mic. This only happen with this headphone, with other headphones works ok and the mic of my laptop also works fine without any issue

other issue (but i could live with this): Sometimes the volume dancing (appear analog output in the ubuntu ui like I touch the volume up and down button) in the ui randomly.



➜  ~ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec 
Codec: Nvidia GPU 94 HDMI/DP 
Codec: Realtek ALC233



➜/tmp uname -a
Linux christian-TUF-Gaming-FX505DT-FX505DT 6.5.0-44-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP 
PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jun 18 14:36:16 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



➜  /tmp lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:  22.04
Codename: jammy


When I connect the dongle I saw this:

[65311.940329] usb 3-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[65312.076444] usb 3-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=047f, idProduct=02e9, bcdDevice= 2.18
[65312.076455] usb 3-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[65312.076460] usb 3-2.1: Product: Poly BT700
[65312.076464] usb 3-2.1: Manufacturer: Plantronics
[65312.076468] usb 3-2.1: SerialNumber: 56B24EA9171249A1ABA1A8F59EC47FB3
[65312.148995] plantronics 0003:047F:02E9.0017: No inputs registered, leaving
[65312.149268] plantronics 0003:047F:02E9.0017: hiddev2,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [Plantronics Poly BT700] on usb-0000:05:00.4-2.1/input0
[65335.751849] usb 3-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 25
[65336.076334] usb 3-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[65336.212844] usb 3-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=047f, idProduct=02e8, bcdDevice= 2.18
[65336.212861] usb 3-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[65336.212871] usb 3-2.1: Product: Poly BT700
[65336.212879] usb 3-2.1: Manufacturer: Plantronics
[65336.212887] usb 3-2.1: SerialNumber: 56B24EA9171249A1ABA1A8F59EC47FB3
[65337.506384] input: Plantronics Poly BT700 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2.1/3-2.1:1.3/0003:047F:02E8.0018/input/input59
[65337.568994] plantronics 0003:047F:02E8.0018: input,hiddev2,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [Plantronics Poly BT700] on usb-0000:05:00.4-2.1/input3


